# Bash: While-read loop skips the last line of comma-separated text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am trying to read some comma-separated data from a text file, parse it and calculate average of column-5.
The input is in the following form:

```
Computer ID,User ID,M,T,W,T,F
Computer1,User3,5,7,3,5,2
Computer2,User5,8,8,8,8,8
Computer3,User4,0,8,0,8,4
```

I am using the following script for this:

```
hours = 0
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
do
((hours = hours + col5))
echo "$col1, $col2"
done < <(tail -n+2 user-list.txt)
echo "$hours"
```

The problem with the script is that it does not read / parse the last line of the text.
What can I do about that?

Also, every time I run the script, the value of `hours` keeps on increasing (probably the previous value is stored). How can the value be defaulted to zero everytime the script runs?

TIA

Comment: are you sure that's all code that matters? I tried your code (on ubuntu18) - it works perfectly fine for me and resets hours to 0 every time - you must have something more that operates on these data and creates the error

Comment: @Drako yes, thats all the code. If its working fine for you, then it might be something with my linux environment. I am using windows subsystem for linux (WSL).

Comment: I'm also using Ubuntu 18 on WSL -1, but then its really weird

Comment: This is the answer I'm getting:
Computer1, User3
Computer2, User5
Computer3, User4
11

Comment: oh - the only difference - I called file with contents test.txt - may be "-" in your version makes issues, but sounds unrealistic

Comment: Your `user-list.txt` file may be created on Windows and the last line may not contain newline character at the end of file. Then please try to modify the `while` line as: `while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 || [[ -n $col1 ]]`.

Comment: @tshiono - would you know how can I perform a floating point calculation?Currently, the output of the script is of integer type.

Comment: `bash` cannot perform floating point math calculations. You may need to use `bc` or switch to other language such as `awk`.

Comment: Note that with `awk`, the whole script is just `awk 'NR>1{hours += $5} END{print hours/10}' user-list.txt`.  With `datamash` it's just `datamash --header-in -t, sum 5 <user-list.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
hours=0
#echo "\n" >> user-list.txt
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 || [[ -n $col1 ]]
do
    ((hours = hours + col5))
    #echo "$col1, $col2"
done < <(tail -n+2 user-list.txt)

((hours = hours/10))
echo "$hours"
```